# Upload file to google drive after http get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-drive-api

I have two functions in separate files to split up the workflow.

```
const download = function(url){
    const file = fs.createWriteStream("./test.png");
    const request = https.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
    });
}
```

This function in my `fileHelper.js` is supposed to take a URL with an image in it and then save it locally to `test.png`

```
function uploadFile(filePath) {
    fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
        // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), function (auth) {
            const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
            const fileMetadata = {
            'name': 'testphoto.png'
            };
            const media = {
            mimeType: 'image/png',
            body: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            };
            drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetadata,
            media: media,
            fields: 'id'
            }, (err, file) => {
            if (err) {
                // Handle error
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
            }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This function in my `googleDriveHelper.js` is supposed to take the filePath of call and then upload that stream into my google drive. These two functions work on their own but it seems that the https.get works asynchronously and if I try to call the `googleDriveHelper.uploadFile(filePath)` function after the download, it doesn't have time to get the full file to upload so instead a blank file will be uploaded to my drive.

- I want to find a way so that when the `fileHelper.download(url)` is called, it automatically uploads into my drive.
- I also don't know if there is a way to create a readStream directly from the `download` function to the `upload` function, so I can avoid having to save the file locally to upload it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to upload a file retrieving from an URL to Google Drive.
- When you download the file from the URL, you want to upload it to Google Drive without creating the file.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to upload a file using Drive API.

For this, how about this answer?

### Modification points:

- At `download` function, the retrieved buffer is converted to the stream type, and the stream data is returned.
- At `uploadFile` function, the retrieved stream data is used for uploading.
- When the file ID is retrieved from the response value of Drive API, please use `file.data.id` instead of `file.id`.

By above modification, the file downloaded from the URL can be uploaded to Google Drive without creating a file.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### `download()`

```
const download = function (url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(
      {
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        encoding: null,
      },
      (err, res, body) => {
        if (err && res.statusCode != 200) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        const stream = require("stream");
        const bs = new stream.PassThrough();
        bs.end(body);
        resolve(bs);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

#### `uploadFile()`

```
function uploadFile(data) { // <--- Modified
  fs.readFile("drive_credentials.json", (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), function (auth) {
      const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
      const fileMetadata = {
        name: "testphoto.png",
      };
      const media = {
        mimeType: "image/png",
        body: data, // <--- Modified
      };
      drive.files.create(
        {
          resource: fileMetadata,
          media: media,
          fields: "id",
        },
        (err, file) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            console.log("File Id: ", file.data.id); // <--- Modified
          }
        }
      );
    });
  });
}
```

#### For testing

For example, when above scripts are tested, how about the following script?

```
async function run() {
  const url = "###";
  const data = await fileHelper.download(url);
  googleDriveHelper.uploadFile(data);
}
```

### References:

- [Class: stream.PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough)
- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough)